# Not able to get 1080p resolution when connecting laptop to full HD TV

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, tv, windows-10-v1607

So we have a new FHD Tv and I tried to connect it to my laptop just to check gaming/video capabilities.
I connected them through a HDMI cable, which supports 4K and 3D as well.

My laptop’s display resolution is 1600x900 and it has Nvidia GT 650M graphic card.
Tv’s display is 1920x1080.

So the problem is, when I connected, the visual quality wasn’t nice and I checked the display settings of Windows 10.
It shows 720 and 1600x900 options but doesn’t show 1920x1080 option in resolution settings.
I have also cross-checked the “show only in 2“ option which outputs to only the Tv.
I have tried the same thing with another desktop monitor of 1920x1080 resolution screen. Same issue happens.

Does it mean my laptop can’t push to 1920x1080 resolution or do I have some issue here?

Note: I did not use "mirror" mode or "extended mode". I have verified the option to show only in tv monitor.

Note 2: The laptop model I have is Samsung NP550P5C-S05IN. It has Intel HD Graphics 4000 and Nvidia GT 650M gpu.

Comment: Find out which graphic card your laptop has, and look up its specs. It might not support the resolution. Also, maybe it only supports HDMI 1.1 or other older standards, which do not go that high.

Comment: Hi @Aganju, here is the gpu specs link - https://www.geforce.com/hardware/notebook-gpus/geforce-gt-650m/specifications. It says, Maximum Digital Resolution - 3840 x 2160 and Maximum VGA Resolution - Up to 2048x1536

Comment: @Aganju, the laptop also has Intel HD Graphics 4000 card. But I am not sure which gpu card is actually managing the display when I connect to tv

Comment: The link does only list ‘HDMI’, without a version, which points to an older HDMI standard - newer standards would proudly claim so. If you google ‘GT 650M HDMI’ you find many people with your problem.

Answer (score 0):

It should work, but you cannot use a "mirror" mode because it will be limited to your internal display size. If you can see the same image on your laptop monitor as your TV then you are "mirroring".

You either need to "extend" your monitor, or use the TV as your only display. If the displays show completely different images then you are in "extended" mode, if you *only* see a display on your TV then you are in single display mode.

Then you should be able to set the resolution correctly.

Comment: I did not use mirror mode or extended mode. I have also mentioned I have cross checked the option "show only in 2", like show only in tv.

Comment: Are you using the Nvidia panel to change resolution? If I remember correctly you might need to scroll to the bottom of the list for "TV" display modes...

Comment: I am using Windows 10 settings menu to check the resolution. I did not find any display modes as in Nvidia panel

Comment: @Karthik it should look something like this: https://international.download.nvidia.com/geforce-com/international/images/geforce-garage/how-to-calibrate-your-monitor/nvidia-control-panel-native-resolution.png but scroll through the list as I think it separates "PC" and "TV" resolutions.

Comment: Mokubai, there are no such settings in the Nvidia Control panel in my laptop. There is only the first tab, "3D settings". Rest of the display and video tabs are not present.

Comment: @Karthik it sounds like something is corrupt in your display driver if those are missing... seems odd but a bit common on Google: https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=nvidia+control+panel+resolution+missing its only a guess but you might be able to do a complete clean install of the drivers? Could be one of the Windows update/reinstalls broke something as hey have for me in the past.